# Call class method within D3 method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JS class where I'm using D3. I've created a button element that I need to execute a class function upon being pressed. What is the proper way to do this?

```
class MyClass{
...
   foo(bar){
      d3.select("button").on("click",function(){ this.print(bar) });
   }

   print(text){
      console.log(text);
   }
}
```

As far as I know, going within the scope of `function(){..}` loses the binding of `this` and the instance of `MyClass`, because it claims that `this.print()` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

To do it you can save your class instance inside a variable

in my sample

```
let _this = this;
```

And use this new variable in your d3 function

```js
class MyClass{
...
   foo(bar){
      let _this = this;
      d3.select("button").on("click",function(){ _this.print(bar) });
   }

   print(text){
      console.log(text);
   }
}
```

Comment: That works for that simple example great! However, what happens if I need to update some class variable inside `print()`?

Comment: it will run `this` inside print function don't change and continue match to the class instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function to keep the reference to the instance's `this` context. In the words of the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions):

> In [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`.

Your code could thus be rewritten as

```
d3.select("button").on("click", () => this.print(bar));
```